# DRF. ModelSerializer вернуть вместо списка словарь

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**models.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    # и ещё с десяток полей
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ItemSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('title', 'other_fields',)
```

**views.py**

```
class ItemsView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        section = self.kwargs['section']
        return Item.objects.select_related().filter(
            user=user,
            item_prototype__item_type__section=section
        )
```

На выходе получаю, как и ожидалось:

```
[
    {
        "item_prototype": {
            "pk": 1,
            "title": "Title",
            "description": ""
            // И т.д.
        },
        "user": {
            "username": "Admin"
        }
        // И прочие поля...
    }
]
```

Но мне надо ещё добавить общее поле в результат с количеством выбранных item'ов, ну, и ещё парочку. Собственно вопрос: Как заставить DRF возвращать не список, а словарь? Что-то вроде такого:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "item_prototype": {
                "pk": 1,
                "title": "Title",
                "description": ""
                // И т.д.
            },
            "user": {
                "username": "Admin"
            }
            // И прочие поля...
        }
    ],
    "count_items": 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно расширить метод:

```
class ItemsView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        section = self.kwargs['section']
        return Item.objects.select_related().filter(
            user=user,
            item_prototype__item_type__section=section
        )

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        old_response_data = super(ItemsView, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        new_response_data = {"items": old_response_data.data, "count_items": len(old_response_data.data)}
        return Response(new_response_data)
```

Comment: Спасибо, что-то метод list как-то упускал из вида постоянно. Получил желаемый результат. Только у вас в ответе есть не большие не точности: в создаваемом словаре надо не просто подставлять old_response_data, а old_response_data.data и в конце возвращать не просто return new_response_data, а return Response(new_response_data).